# About Utterly odd numbers.

Tags: number-theory, experimental-mathematics

Consider the following sequence defined here https://oeis.org/A079523 of utterly odd numbers: These are numbers such whose binary representation ends in an odd number of ones.

If $n$ is an utterly odd number, then show that $n+64$ is also an utterly odd number. I did some computer experiments and I think that this is true. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What do you mean as “the ending number of $1$s” in your statement? This part confuses me.

Comment: Count the number of $1$s from the end of the binary representation of $n$

Comment: It could be $0.$

Comment: @Clayton Look at the sequence. OP wrote it in a very confusing way.

Comment: Does $B(7)=3, B(11)=2$ then?

Comment: @saulspatz I think so.

Comment: Yes. That is true.

Comment: Why is $B(10)=0$? This is why I am confused. Should it not be $2$? And $B(13)=3$?

Comment: @Clayton $10=1010_2$, so the ending number of $1s$ is $0$. Hence, $\forall k\in\mathbb N$, $B(2k)=0$.

Comment: @Rushabh: by ending number of $1$s, are you just looking at the last digit in the binary representation?

Comment: @Clayton You look at the largest sequence of $1s$ at the end of the binary expansion. Ex: $B(10111_2)=3$, while $B(11101_2)=1$.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. It is the length of the string of $1$s at the end. Right? If the binary representation ends in $0$, the length of the string of $1$s at the end is $0$.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true.

Let $127=1111111_2$. Note that $B(127)=7$. But, since $64=1000000_2$, $$127+64=10111111_2$$ so $B(127+64)=6$.

Comment: But $B(127+256)$ is odd. I know I might have missed something. But there is clearly a pattern here.

Comment: @Hello_World I don't think so, I can find an example that disproves 256 as well.

Comment: No I am not saying that $256$ is the constant that works.

Comment: @Hello_World I don't think there is any constant that "works"

Comment: In fact, the numbers need not be constant, but they are $4,16,64,256,1024\dots$

Comment: @Hello_World I'm not sure what you are arguing here.

Comment: I claimed that adding a fixed number say $64$ would still make the number utterly odd.

Comment: @Hello_World sure, but that was false

Comment: But what I am saying is that for each number there is a distinct number that will work.

Comment: It could be $4,16,64$ or $256$ (works for $127$). For $511$  the number $1024$ works.  If you give me a few minutes I can explain you what I am trying to do here.

Comment: @Hello_World Isn't that obvious? Find $n$ such that $2^{n-1}>x$. Then, if $B(x)$, then $B(x+2^n)$

Comment: Ahh, that's stupid of me. I will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean $2^{n-1}\leq x<2^{n}.$

Comment: @Hello_World No I do not.

Answer (score -1):

For a number to be utterly odd, the number of its binary digits is odd.
For example, we have the number 
*Converting it into binary:*

**$$19 = 10011_2$$**  where we have total five (odd number) of binary digits

and in the same way, if we see 18,

**$$18 = 10010_2$$** It also consists of an odd number of digits in binary.

So, conclusion:

> A number is called an utterly odd number if it consists of an odd number of digits in its binary representation(omitting zeros on the left side if any )

Now, we check the term **n+64** if it is utterly odd or not.
64 has 7 binary digits i.e. 1000000
it will remain a 7 digit binary for $$X<64$$
Because at n=64, 
the expression becomes,
$$ (64+64) =128 $$
Which in binary consists of 8 digits

For n=1 till 200,
the values of n for which $$(n+64)$$ is an utterly odd number are:

$$[0,63] U [192,448] U [960, 1983]$$

let's check the size of the intervals,

length of the first interval is $$63= 2^6-1$$

Second interval length = $$448-192=2^8$$

and Similarly for the third one,
$$1983-960=1023=2^{10} -1$$

So, the length of the interval **k** in which we get an utterly odd number is :

$$f(k) = {2^2k -1,    {k = Odd}}$$
and $$f(k) =  {2^2k ,  {k = Even} }$$

So, the final conclusion:

> $$n+64$$ is not an utterly odd number for every n, however, it behaves as an utterly odd number in some intervals

Comment: Actually, $19=10011_2$.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that now, thanks